# Selenium WebDriver: Can anyone help me out in getting the tooltip?

Tags: webdriver, java, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to get the tool tip from a tag. The snippet of the HTML is

```
  <table class="tiger-stripe" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
  <tr class="oddrow">
  <tr>
  <td>
  <td>
  <div id="div_2" class="betterTip fltlt">
   <p id="a_2" class="betterTip" lang="$div_2_Tip?width=300" title="">
  </div>
  <div id="div_2_Tip" class="ToolTip" style="display:none">
  <p class="Tooltip">Evaluate value : 400.00</p>
  <p class="Tooltip">Actual value : 646.69</p>
 <p class="Tooltip">Description : Payment Amount Back must be < Max Payment.</p>
 </div>
 </td>
```

Here in the above html code the tool tip location is in the first paragraph tab but the tool tip text is present in the next paragraph tag

I am trying to get the tool tip from various methods like `getText()`, `getAttribute()` but no use. Can any one help me out?[image]

Code :

```
Actions a =new Actions(driver);    

a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='tiger-stripe']/tbod‌​y/tr[2]/td[2]/div[@id='div_2']/p[@id='a_2']"))).perform(); 

String toolTipText1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='tiger-stripe']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/di‌v[@id='div_2']/p[@id='a_2']")).getAttribute("title"); 

System.out.println("tool tip text: "+toolTipText1)
```

Comment: what code you have written?

Comment: Actions a =new Actions(driver);                  a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='tiger-stripe']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div[@id='div_2']/p[@id='a_2']"))).perform();
String toolTipText1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='tiger-stripe']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div[@id='div_2']/p[@id='a_2']")).getAttribute("title");
            System.out.println("tool tip text: "+toolTipText1)

Comment: please don't concentrate on the code, i have attached the html snap, check it once

Comment: Seems you are using incorrect xpath

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath doesn't seem to be correct.

```
String toolTipText1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='tiger-stripe']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/di‌v[@id='div_2']/p[@id='a_2']")).getAttribute("title");
```

If you see your HTML, the text that is shown in the tooltip is contained in another div id then what you are using. Also, you're trying to get the title attribute, which as per the HTML is blank.

Try using this

```
   String toolTipText1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='tiger-stripe']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/di‌v[@id='div_2_Tip']/p[@class='Tooltip']")).getText();
```

Comment: I tried earlier, no it is not working, please give me a solution

Comment: what are you gwtting when you're using this

Comment: Nothing, null is getting as a value

Comment: String toolTipText1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='tiger-stripe']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/di‌v[@id='div_2_Tip']/p[1]. getText( ) does this print anything?

Comment: yes it prints "null" as a value

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Actions for this. in this am printing the mouse hover message in Google

```
    Actions ToolTip1 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement googleLogo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='hplogo']"));

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    ToolTip1.clickAndHold(googleLogo).perform();
```

Perform mouse hover action using 'clickAndHold' method.

Get the value of Tool tip by using 'getAttribute' command

```
    String ToolTipText = googleLogo.getAttribute("title");

    Assert.assertEquals(ToolTipText, "Google");

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Tooltip value is: " + ToolTipText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<WebElement> webElements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='Tooltip']"));   
         for(int i=0;i< webElements.size(); i++)   
         {  
         System.out.println(webElements.get(i).getText());  
         }
```

This should print the text for all the tool-tips present here as the class name for all the tool-tips is "Tooltip"

Answer (score 0):

We use `getAttribute("title");` to get the tooltip text of a webelement. In this please make sure that the webelement is not inside another iframe.

I found one more thing from the html snapshot you provided. That is the element is having an attribute called "title", whose value is "" (Empty string). So probably you will get printed the empty string.

If the above things followed and not solved your problem. Kindly let us know the exception thrown(if any).